# Is there a way to run a browser plug-in or add-on command via javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser-extension

Is there a way to run a browser (IE) plug-in or add-on command via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

press `F12` in ie. You'll get into developer tools, and click the `console` tab